# How to install expo cli correctly?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to install expo cli globally but I am getting errors:

```
OS: Catalina 10.15.4
Node: 14.6

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mac/.npm/_logs/2020-07-25T10_36_46_119Z-debug.log
```

I install in the Visual Studio terminal, I also tried to install through the console, but the result did not change

Comment: sudo npm install package -g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing some packages globally, you need to do so as a privileged user. On Mac, use `sudo` to elevate the installation command. E.g. `sudo npm install your-package -g`